# Loop calling update() method of each class with different parameters

Tags: java

Say I have 3 different classes (Class1, Class2, Class3),  and each class has a method called ".update(String x)".

Now I want to read a line in a .csv file, I separate the values by comma and get a list with each string value indexed , for example "Foo, bar, barz" becomes {"foo", "bar", "barz").

Is it possible in Java to make a list of objects (Obj1, Obj2, Obj3), one for each class and for each value on my list of strings, call the .update of each object with the according index of my list of strings as the parameter?

for example:

```
package Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Class1{
    private String string;

    public void update(String s){
            this.string = s;
    }

    public String str(){
        return this.string;
    }
}


class Class2{
    private String string;

    public void update(String s){
        this.string = s;
    }

    public String str(){
        return this.string;
    }
}


class Class3{
    private String string;

    public void update(String s){
        this.string = s;
    }

    public String str(){
        return this.string;
    }
}

public class Testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Object> object = new ArrayList<Object>();

        Class1 class1 = new Class1();
        Class2 class2 = new Class2();
        Class3 class3 = new Class3();

        object.add(class1);
        object.add(class2);
        object.add(class3);

        String string_list[] = {"foo" , "bar", "barz"};

        for(int i = 0 ; i < object.size(); i++) {
            object.get(i).update(string_list[i]);
        }
    }
}

hence obj1.update("foo"), obj2.update("bar"), obj3.update("barz")
```

I keep getting a "cannot resolve method" error in the loop.

```
Error:(68, 26) java: cannot find symbol 
symbol:   method update(java.lang.String)
location: class java.lang.Object)
```

But when I change the object reference in the loop to an object and not a reference it works fine. Logically it seems correct, but it seems like an ArrayList list isn't the right data structure to hold objects? or maybe it is and I'm doing it wrong, anyone have any suggestions why it's not working and how I can fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: Post the full error message.

Comment: Error:(68, 26) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method update(java.lang.String)
  location: class java.lang.Object

Comment: What language is this? Where is the code you tried?

Comment: It is java hence the tag "java"

Comment: Your `object` list only guarantees that it's contents are `Object`s, there fore when you use `objects.get` you get back a `Object` which clearly doesn't have a `update` method.  You would need to either have a common ancestor from which your three classes descended from or use `instaneof` to determine if the current object is a type of a specific object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do that, but for that you need your list of objects to be of a type that declares the update() method. If you want the objects to be of different classes, you need to have some interface or abstract class that all three implement/extend, and that interface/abstract class should declare update method.

should be something like this:

```
public interface MyInterface {
  public void update(String str);
}

public class Object1 implements MyInterface {
  @Override
  public void update(String str) {
  ...
  }
}

/// same for object 2 and 3

String[] string_list = {"foo", "bar", "barz"}
MyInterface[] obj_list = {Obj1, Obj2, Obj3}

...
...
```